# Chat Server Using C# for iPhone and Android Mobiles

Tags: c#, tcp

I am a c# developer and have to provide my iphone and android developers a facility that they can implement in their apps to chat across the devices. After working on different tutorials i came to a solution for **socket programming** using TCP/IP.

I started following a very simple code, in fact copying the given example. The server and client source codes are given below.

> Server

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        TcpListener serverSocket = new TcpListener(8888);
        TcpClient clientSocket = default(TcpClient);
        int counter = 0;
        serverSocket.Start();
        Console.WriteLine("Chat Server Started ....");
        counter = 0;

        while ((true))
        {
            try
            {
                counter += 1;
                clientSocket = serverSocket.AcceptTcpClient();

                byte[] bytesFrom = new byte[10025];
                string dataFromClient = null;

                NetworkStream networkStream = clientSocket.GetStream();
                networkStream.Read(bytesFrom, 0, (int)clientSocket.ReceiveBufferSize);
                dataFromClient = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytesFrom);
                dataFromClient = dataFromClient.Substring(0, dataFromClient.IndexOf("$"));
                clientsList.Add(dataFromClient, clientSocket);
                broadcast(dataFromClient + " Joined ", dataFromClient, false);

                Console.WriteLine(dataFromClient + " Joined chat room ");
                handleClinet client = new handleClinet();
                client.startClient(clientSocket, dataFromClient, clientsList);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ErrorOccured(ex);
            }
        }

        clientSocket.Close();
        serverSocket.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("exit");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

When i try connecting my windows form test client, on server i face the below exception.

> System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Specified argument was out of the range of valid values.
>   Parameter name: size

on below code line.

```
networkStream.Read(bytesFrom, 0, (int)clientSocket.ReceiveBufferSize);
```

Have checked the network stream, it CanRead = true, but DataAvailable=false.

> My client code is given below.

```
    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            readData = "Conected to Chat Server ...";
            msg();
            clientSocket.Connect("127.0.0.1", 8888);
            serverStream = clientSocket.GetStream();
            byte[] outStream = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(textBox3.Text + "$");
            serverStream.Write(outStream, 0, outStream.Length);
            serverStream.Flush();

            Thread ctThread = new Thread(getMessage);
            ctThread.Start();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ErrorOccured(ex);
        }
    }
```

No error while connecting or writing to the network stream. But, when my client tries to read data from server using below code, same exception occurs on line **serverStream.Read(inStream, 0, buffSize);**.

```
    private void getMessage()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            try
            {
                serverStream = clientSocket.GetStream();
                    int buffSize = 0;
                    byte[] inStream = new byte[10025];
                    buffSize = clientSocket.ReceiveBufferSize;
                    serverStream.Read(inStream, 0, buffSize);
                    string returndata = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(inStream);
                    readData = "" + returndata;
                    msg();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ErrorOccured(ex);
                break;
            }
        }

    }
```

Can anyone help me out in this situation?

Comment: on networkStream.Read(bytesFrom, 0, (int)clientSocket.ReceiveBufferSize);, for both server and client, it is mentioned in question.

Comment: What is the value of `clientSocket.ReceiveBufferSize` at the time of exception?

Comment: As can be noted in the docs (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.networkstream.read.aspx) this exception is called when size is less than zero, or if buffSize is larger than your buffer size. Could either of these be true? Is buffSize perhaps -1?

Comment: the buffer size is 65536, no buffer size is 10025 as mentioned in code

Comment: What buffer size is 65536, `clientSocket.ReceiveBufferSize`? If yes, I think you have your answer

Comment: bytesFrom length is 10025 and clientSocket.ReceiveBufferSize=65536. should i set byteform length as 65536 or change my code to read bytesFrom.length

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue you are having is related to not knowing how much data to receive. Instead of receiving "everything available" this can be solved in another way.

The usual way of sending strings (or any data) is to use some sort of protocol. A common protocol is prefixing the data that is sent with an int that tells the receiving part how much data it should receive in the next batch. So you could have a send method similar to this

```
public void Send(string message, NetworkStream stream) {
  byte[] strbuf = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(message);
  byte[] intbuf = BitConverter.GetBytes(System.Net.IPAddress.HostToNetworkOrder(strbuf.Length));
  stream.Write(intbuf, 0, intbuf.Length);
  stream.Write(strbuf, 0, strbuf.Length);
}
```

In this method I'm using [IPAddress.HostToNetworkOrder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/653kcke1.aspx), since you mentioned several platforms. The `BitConverter` class in C# converts to big-endian byte arrays, and `HostToNetworkOrder` converts that to little-endian so other platforms can read it. Basically you just reverse the array, so this can be done using `Array.Reverse` in either platform.

And then to receive you just do it the other way around;

```
public string Receive(NetworkStream stream) {
  byte[] intbuf = new byte[4];
  stream.Read(intbuf, 0, intbuf.Length);
  int length = System.Net.IPAddress.NetworkToHostOrder(BitConverter.ToInt32(intbuf, 0));

  byte[] strbuf = new byte[length];
  stream.Read(strbuf, 0, strbuf.Length);
  string message = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(strbuf);
  return message;
}
```

Comment: perfect, yeah its my solution. thanks. but one more thing, i am using a while(true) loop on reading end for both client and server. isn't it costly performance wise? i have to 1000 threads to accommodate my multiple clients, is there any event based mechanism?

Comment: Well, when you read from the socket the thread waits for input (and is notified by the socket when data is available) so as long as you do that in its own thread you should be okay.

Comment: In regards to multiple threads, you can solve that by using the asynchronous methods available in socket, and/or use a polling solution, where you have one thread that checks if data is available in any socket, and starts to process data at that time.

Comment: yes polling is good, i am planning to implement producer and worker pattern to get rid of limitation. I put clients in a dictionary, a producer thread will traverse from the client dictionary and will check if data is avaialble in any socket, if yes then will put in a command queue. another thread will dequeue the command ques and will process

Comment: @LojiSmith: That's sounds like a good plan. You can create a similar pattern for receiving messages. When a message is received, put that in a `BlockingCollection` for instance and have another dequeue thread pick that up and send a "MessageReceived" event to listening classes.

Comment: yiippy have done it already, 4 threads, ClientRegistrar, CommandListener, CommandEvaluator and HouseKeeper

Answer (score 0):

You've accepted an answer that fails to directly address the original question, i.e. why you are getting `ArgumentOutOfRangeException`. The answer to that was answered in the comments, but you never really acknowledged that.

So, just for completeness for future readers (who appear to be copying from the same buggy source that you have), the main problem is here:

```
                byte[] inStream = new byte[10025];
                buffSize = clientSocket.ReceiveBufferSize;
                serverStream.Read(inStream, 0, buffSize);
```

The value of `ReceiveBufferSize` has nothing to do with the length of the array you pass to the `Read()` method. It's referencing the socket's own buffer size. The size you need to pass to the `Read()` method must be no larger than the length of the buffer being passed, but you're passing a much larger number (65535, whereas the buffer's length is 10025).

The code should be changed to read more like this:

```
                byte[] inStream = new byte[10025];
                serverStream.Read(inStream, 0, inStream.Length);
```

Then you can fix your other bug, in which you fail to take into account the actual number of bytes read, like so:

```
                byte[] inStream = new byte[10025];
                int bytesRead = serverStream.Read(inStream, 0, inStream.Length);
                string returndata =
                    System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(inStream, 0, bytesRead);
```

It's great if you found the other answer useful. It's not how I'd approach the problem, but there's nothing fundamentally wrong with it and if it works for you, that's good indeed. I hope the above will prove useful to other visitors who would like something more focused on the specific problem at hand.